# Why update_attribute firing validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have two disabled textbox. And it's passing nil as value.

Still update_attribute is firing validation for those textboxes.

As per my knowledge update_attribute should not update the spefic column which has nil value passed.

```
validates_inclusion_of :text_response_time, :in => 0..60, :message => " should be between 0 to 60 minutes."

(rdb:589) params[:test][:text_response_time]
nil
(rdb:589) @test.update_attributes!(params[:test])
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: Text response time  should be between 0 to 60 minutes.
```

Any Idea!

Answer (score 1):

update attributes always validates the entire object, hence why you keep getting the failed validation.  your options would then be to either simply use update_attribute (which ignores validation) or use conditional validation as described in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations)

Answer (score 0):

To further illustrate:

```
@test.update_attribute(:test, params[:test][:text_response_time])
```

will save without validation.

Another strategy that may work in your situation is to only validate on creation (and not updates):

```
validates_inclusion_of :text_response_time, :in => 0..60,
  :message => "should be between 0 to 60 minutes.", :on => :create
```